# box2d border not bordering

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

I'm creating a box2d border for my game and noticing that I can actually slide my bodies across the border.

If I'm tossing them at the border, they bounce back from it. But when I'm slowly moving them towards it, they simply go through. Sometimes, when I have several bodies connected with a `RevoluteJoint` the joint actually gets entangled in the border and stops the sliding. But when not joined, the border doesn't stop the bodies / sprites.

Now, I'm testing it only on the simulator, and don't have an iPad for testing yet. So is this issue connected to the simulator? Mine is running about 30fps.

And if it's not a simulator issue, is there a solution?

The code I'm using is the one you find everywhere (modified a bit to fit my needs:)

```
b2BodyDef groundBodyDef;
groundBodyDef.position.Set(0,0);   
_groundBody = _world->CreateBody(&groundBodyDef);
_groundBody->SetType(b2_staticBody);


b2EdgeShape groundEdge;
b2FixtureDef boxShapeDef;
boxShapeDef.shape = &groundEdge;

//wall definitions
groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(-winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, (float)20/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2((winSize.width)/PTM_RATIO, (float)20/PTM_RATIO)); // bottom wall
_groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(-winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, (winSize.height-50)/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2(winSize.width/PTM_RATIO, (winSize.height-50)/PTM_RATIO)); // top wall
_groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2(-(winSize.width-20)/PTM_RATIO,0), b2Vec2(-(winSize.width-20)/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO)); // left wall
_groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef);

groundEdge.Set(b2Vec2((winSize.width-20)/PTM_RATIO, winSize.height/PTM_RATIO), b2Vec2((winSize.width-20)/PTM_RATIO, 0)); // right wall
_groundBody->CreateFixture(&boxShapeDef); 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a mouse joint to move things, try setting the collideConnected of the mouse joint to true (the default is false).

Comment: Actually while at it, now when I'm pushing the bodies against the border they sometime start shaking. This happens when two different fixtures of the body hit the wall in two different spots. I don't think it's related to the border per se, because it also happens when two different colliding bodies hit each other. And it seems "normal" because the pressure point is moving from one fixture to another, and so the shaking effect happens. But obviously it's an unwanted behavior. Is there a solution?

Comment: I don't think there is any way to avoid that, except for maybe reducing the strength of the mouse joint. I'm not sure, but I would guess that at some point, if the force of the mouse joint was weaker the body would settle instead of continuously being caught between where the mouse joint wants it to go, and where the border wants it to go.

Comment: Yeah, decreasing the mouseJoint's max force does improve the effect, but I like a strong mouse joint.. Playing with the frequencyHz and dampingRatio also helps. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This could have several reasons. Two reasons that could cause the problem:

- The bodies you want to collide with the border are in **another collision group** than the border is
- try to set `setBullet(true)` for all bodies as your problem could be the so called **tunneling effect**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your dynamic objects might have no mass.
Try adding ResetMassData() after creating their fixtures.

If this doesn't help I still assume that the problem is in the dynamic bodies. The generating code is required then.